# How to decide how to normalize a given feature in a data set?

Tags: distributions, normalization

I have two features that differ in their orders of magnitude and also in the way they are distributed. I am aware of two ways of normalization:

1) $\frac{x - x_{min}}{x_{max} - x_{min}}$

2) $\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}$

What are the criteria involved in deciding which normalization method is to be used?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve. One gives numbers on 0-1, the other zero-centered with most of the values between about -2 and 2 (at least 3/4 of them by Chebyshev). Both resolve the magnitude problem. Both preserve order. In other circumstances, you might want to do other things.

Answer (score 1):

The more common is the number 2)

Normalize by the variance means that a variable that has small oscillation will be considered as much important as one that has a large oscillation.

It can be useful if you know that a small oscillation of a variable can be as much important as a large oscillation of another variable.

The first type of normalization instead make your variable between 0 and 1 .  It is less used in statistics and can be useful to compare variables that are on a different scale.

You can for example consider $x\in [1,2]$ and $y\in [2,3]$  and obtain $\hat x, \hat y \in [0,1]$

The decision between normalization 1 and normalization 2 depends on the application and from what you are looking for.